# how to call insert method in different form c#

Tags: c#

This is my insert code in my form1

```
public void insertJob()
{
    CCSLABDataSetTableAdapters.JobOrderTableAdapter JobOrderInsertQueryAdapter = new CCSLABDataSetTableAdapters.JobOrderTableAdapter();
            JobOrderInsertQueryAdapter.JobOrderInsertQuery(
                txtJobID.Text,
                txtJobActDate.Text,
                "",
                 "99-9999-99",
                "PAJAR",
                "LENON",
                txtJobLabAssistant.Text,
                txtJobLabLastname.Text,
                txtJobLabFirstname.Text,
                txtJobEquipID.Text,
                txtJobEquipType.Text,
                txtJobEquipBrand.Text,
                txtJobEquipModel.Text,
                txtJobEquipSerial.Text,
                txtJobEquipRoom.Text,
                txtJobReportProblem.Text,
                "",
                "DAMAGED",
                "Multiple"
                );
}
```

and this is it when i call form 2

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    form2 f2 = new form2();
    f2.show();
}
```

I want to call the insert method in my form2 by button click.

this is my code in form2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    insertJob();
}
```

its seems that it cannot execute the insert method well.

Comment: There is no error. but when button1_click event that i execute in my form2, it executed insert but it inserts only "99-9999-99","PAJAR","LENON","DAMAGED","MULTIPLE", other textboxes that i fill with text. is not inserted in my table. @ClaudioRedi

Answer (score 0):

First code you wrote seems a constructor for a class.
If it's a function or procedure you must define what return type or void for procedure.

Let's assume that code is a procedure, so the code must look like

```
public void insertJob(){
     // your code here
}
```

and it wrapped in class called Form1.

In class Form2 you must declare a variable for Form1. Here is the complete code

```
public class Form1{
     public void insertJob{
          // your code here
     };

     public void openForm2(){
          Form2 varForm2=new Form2();
          varForm2.varForm1=this;
          varForm2.show();
     }
}

public class Form2{
     public Form1 varForm1;

     public void callInsertJob(){
          varForm1.insertJob();
     }
}
```