# Access a form's methods from other forms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, object, methods

I have a main form, called frmContainer. with two panels, a pnlTitle (holding the title) and a pnlMain. Multiple other forms get loaded into pnlMain. frmContainer.cs has multiple methods which load these forms into pnlMain. e.g. The "Learn or Practice" form, frmLearnOrPractice, would be loaded into pnlMain as follows:

```
        public void loadLearnOrPractice()
    {
        clearCurrentSubform();
        frmLearnOrPractice LearnPage = new frmLearnOrPractice();
        LearnPage.TopLevel = false;
        mainPanel2.Controls.Add(LearnPage);
        titlePanel.BackColor = Color.DarkSeaGreen;
        lblTitle.Text = "Advance your knowledge";
        lblNoForm.Visible = false;

        LearnPage.Show();
    }
```

I would like to be able to call these methods to load forms into pnlMain from other forms in my solution. I have tried to do so as follows, here is the code from the sign up form:
`

```
    private void btnBegin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //add user to database e.g. backend.AddUserToDB(.,.,.)
        //THEN run login function in backend e.g. backend.Login(.,.,.)


        //as first time login, if user is a teacher, load frmManageClasses into 
        //container so they can start forming their groups of students.
        //trying to do this part below:
       
        frmContainer container = new Container();
        container.loadManageClasses();
    }`
```

My issue here is I don't want to make a new object of frmContainer as it already exists, and I want to access the methods of the existing frmContainer object. (It was created from the following code in frmLogin if this helps!):

```
    frmContainer container = new frmContainer();

    public void btnBegin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //backend.Login(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        //if returned true, load the correct form(s)
        container.Location = this.Location;
        container.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

How can I make this existing frmContainer object's functions accessible in all of my other forms? Is it possible to turn frmContainer into a global object somehow?

Comment: There are a bunch of questions like this. Have you checked that none of them answers your question: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672276/how-to-call-mainform-method-in-another-form-in-usercontrol-c-sharp), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218118/how-to-call-parent-form-method-from-child-form-in-c) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383780/how-to-call-insert-method-in-different-form-c-sharp), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689337/c-sharp-form-needs-to-call-method-defined-in-parent-form)

Comment: The proper way to do this is for those forms to raise an event that `frmContainer` handles, then it calls its own method. That's pretty much exactly what happens when you click a `Button`: it raises an event that the form handles and then the form does what's required.

Comment: To implement such a scenario, it is best for you to use the MVP pattern.